Kafka Consumer Data Not Showing in Dash Plotly
I am trying to display the real-time data of heart-rate and Blood-Pressure in the dash plotly graph using Python. In Console of app.py the consumer data is showing but in dash app the graph is showing nothing.
Here is my Producer.py code
import random
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import json
import time

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092', 
                         value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))

def produce_heart_rate_data():
    patient_id = "P001"
    while True:
        data = {
            "patient_id": patient_id,
            "timestamp": time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", time.gmtime()),
            "heart_rate": random.randint(60, 100)  # Simulated heart rate
        }
        producer.send('topic_health_heart', value=data)
        print(f"Produced heart rate: {data}")
        time.sleep(60)

produce_heart_rate_data()

here is my Consumer.py
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import json
import threading
import pandas as pd

# Global variable to store heart rate data
heart_rate_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['patient_id', 'timestamp', 'heart_rate'])

# Create a lock for thread-safe access to the heart_rate_data DataFrame
data_lock = threading.Lock()

def consume_heart_rate_data():
    global heart_rate_data
    try:
        consumer = KafkaConsumer(
            'topic_health_heart',
            bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
            auto_offset_reset='earliest',
            enable_auto_commit=True,
            group_id='heart_rate_monitor_group',
            value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8'))
        )
        for message in consumer:
            data = message.value
            print(f"Patient ID: {data['patient_id']}, Timestamp: {data['timestamp']}, Heart Rate: {data['heart_rate']}")
            
            # Append new data to the DataFrame safely
            new_data = pd.DataFrame([{
                "patient_id": data['patient_id'],
                "timestamp": data['timestamp'],
                "heart_rate": data['heart_rate']
            }])
            
            # Acquire the lock before updating the DataFrame
            with data_lock:
                heart_rate_data = pd.concat([heart_rate_data, new_data], ignore_index=True)
                print(f"Updated heart_rate_data size: {heart_rate_data.shape}")  # Log the size of DataFrame

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error consuming data: {e}")

# Run the Kafka consumer in a separate thread
consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=consume_heart_rate_data)
consumer_thread.start()

and here is my app.py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time

from consumer1 import heart_rate_data, data_lock  # Import shared variables and lock
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# Your local timezone (replace with appropriate timezone)
local_timezone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Karachi')  # Example for Pakistan Standard Time

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Delay to ensure the Kafka consumer has time to populate the data
time.sleep(15)

# App layout with a line chart that updates every 2 seconds
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Real-Time Heart Rate Data"),
    dcc.Graph(id='live-update-graph'),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=2*1000,  # Update every 2 seconds
        n_intervals=0
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('live-update-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
)
def update_graph_live(n):
    global heart_rate_data
    
    # Safely access the heart_rate_data DataFrame using the lock
    with data_lock:
        df = heart_rate_data.copy()

    print(f"Heart rate data in callback: {df}")  # Log DataFrame contents

    if df.empty:
        print("DataFrame is empty in callback")
        return px.line(title="No data yet")

    # Proceed if DataFrame is not empty
    if 'timestamp' in df.columns:
        # Convert timestamp to datetime for better plotting
        df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
        print(f"DataFrame after timestamp conversion: {df}")

        # Create the line graph
        fig = px.line(df, x='timestamp', y='heart_rate', color='patient_id',
                      title="Heart Rate Over Time")

        fig.update_layout(
            xaxis_title="Timestamp",
            yaxis_title="Heart Rate (BPM)",
            xaxis=dict(showline=True, showgrid=False),
            yaxis=dict(showline=True, showgrid=False),
            showlegend=True
        )

        return fig

    return px.line(title="No data yet")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=False)

I am using python-kafka library for Producing and consuming the data. The data is succefully being produced in the kafka topics, even it is displaying in console. The consumer is also showing the data successfully in the console. But when i run the app.py the data is showing in console but not being displayed in the raphs on website. Please need the solution.

I'd suggest using sqlite rather than rebuilding a dataframe for every new record. Otherwise, please provide logs that show the output from Heart rate data in callback
